# svnadmin dump in Cygwin

Tags: svn, cygwin, dump, mount, svnadmin

I'm trying to write a script in Cygwin to backup our SVN repositories nightly.  The first stumbling block I found is that the svnadmin doesn't seem to work quite right within the cygwin bash shell.

My repositories are in C:\Repositories

Doing the following in a cmd shell works fine

```
svnadmin dump C:\Repositories\Thor > Thor.dmp
```

But the following within cygwin does not

```
svnadmin dump /cygdrive/c/Repositories/Thor > Thor.dmp
```

And fails with

```
$ svnadmin dump /cygdrive/c/Repositories/Thor > Thor.dmp
svnadmin: Can't open file '\cygdrive\c\Repositories\Thor\format': The system can
not find the path specified.
```

However the following does work within cygwin

```
$ svnadmin dump 'C:\Repositories\Thor' > Thor.dmp
```

Any suggestions as to why it works on in cmd but not in cygwin?  Do I need to fiddle with the /cygdrive mount points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious now I think about it.  svnadmin is a windows exe that doesn't understand cygwin paths so only the windows version will work.